# QIcon is not showing always on QMenu

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a QMenu and added QIcon on this menu but its now showing always
When mousehover happens on this Qmenu only ICON shows but the menu name is showing always

I want Icon together with Menu name should show always when its parent Menu is clicked

```
Mode2  = preferenceMenu->addMenu(QIcon(":/Img/Queue.png"), tr("&Mode 2"));
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, when exactly the icon is not displayed ?

Comment: Icon is not displaying on default, It displaying only on mouse hover over Mode 2

Comment: The code you gave should work as is, but there may be other problems in what you didn't show. Please provide a [mcve] if you expect useful answers.